# How do I specify multiple constraints on a generic type in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, generics, type-constraints

What is the syntax for placing constraints on multiple types?  The basic example:

```
class Animal<SpeciesType> where SpeciesType : Species
```

I would like to place constraints on both types in the following definition such that `SpeciesType` must inherit from `Species` and `OrderType` must inherit from `Order`:

```
class Animal<SpeciesType, OrderType>
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
public class Animal<SpeciesType,OrderType>
    where SpeciesType : Species
    where OrderType : Order
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks! i always forget this if I do not write it often!

Answer (score 18):

You should be able to go :

```
class Animal<SpeciesType, OrderType>
    where SpeciesType : Species
    where OrderType : Order {
}
```